# plot 3D surface with R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am having a problem ploting my data as a 3D surface using this script:

```
wireframe(Z~X*Y, data=FI02, xlab="X", ylab="Y", main="Surface elevation", drape=TRUE, 
          colorkey=TRUE, screen=list(z=-60, x=-60))
```

The output is just a cube without data / surface (see attachment). What was my mistake?

```
"X" "Y" "Z" "Plot"
552032.707  413894.885  10.8    2
552033.707  413896.585  13.4    2
552036.907  413899.685  18.5    2
552039.307  413898.085  10.5    2
552039.807  413894.585  11.2    2
552044.107  413894.985  9   2
552044.007  413895.035  11.5    2
552043.607  413896.985  13.4    2
552047.407  413897.885  8.2 2
552045.207  413898.985  10.7    2
552042.307  413902.085  9.4 2
552040.907  413902.885  12.5    2
552036.607  413901.585  11.4    2
552036.207  413901.435  12.4    2
552039.907  413905.285  18  2
552036.707  413906.585  9.7 2
552037.407  413908.785  6.3 2
552038.907  413911.085  7.5 2
552039.607  413911.285  16.8    2
552041.107  413908.985  9.5 2
552041.307  413910.385  14.5    2
552042.207  413909.985  9.3 2
552050.707  413911.985  12.5    2
552048.907  413909.985  18.6    2
552044.507  413906.585  6.7 2
552047.807  413904.085  6.8 2
552048.007  413904.285  12.8    2
552050.407  413903.885  9.7 2
552049.107  413909.785  5.2 2
552050.507  413910.785  12.5    2
552052.407  413908.685  16.5    2
552057.907  413910.385  10.3    2
552058.707  413909.785  18.5    2
552058.907  413910.485  12.4    2
552059.707  413908.385  15.3    2
552060.307  413910.785  7.2 2
552061.207  413911.985  11.8    2
552071.007  413912.185  17  2
552068.707  413911.385  8.3 2
552069.107  413910.885  15.5    2
552068.607  413908.485  8   2
```

Comment: What is this data derived from? It is certainly not arranged on an x-y grid as I would have expected for the submission to `wireframe`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see why I don't think this data is well suited for wireframe:

```
cloud(Z~X+Y, data=FI02, xlab="X", ylab="Y", main="Surface elevation", 
              type="l", screen=list(z=-60, x=-60))
```